# Why typescript ReadonlyArrays are mutlabe when they are compiled to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to learn Typescript from the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html). 
And in the [Interfaces section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) I've read the following:

> TypeScript comes with a **ReadonlyArray** type that is the same as
>   **Array** with all mutating methods removed, so you can make sure you
>   don’t change your arrays after creation:

I have played with the following sample code to test the case:

```
let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let ro: ReadonlyArray<number> = a;
ro[0] = 12; // error!
ro.push(5); // error!
ro.length = 100; // error!
a = ro; // error!
```

and I found that the previous code is compiled to javascript like this

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var ro = a;
ro[0] = 12; // works
ro.push(5); // works
ro.length = 100; // works
a = ro; // works
```

You can see that `ro` is mutable now in javascript, and other javascript code can change it, why typescript did not create a subclass of `Array` object where the mutable methods are removed for `ro`?! what I am missing here ?!

Comment: I'd guess no-one thought it was worth it, since any mutation from Typescript would already have been caught, but it's possible it's not possible to do portably, or that using a different class would break optimisations on common JS runtimes, or similar. But hey [they accept patches](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#instructions-for-contributing-code).

Comment: if you create a variable with type boolean in typescript you cant assign string to it.but after compile in to js you can.this is same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TypeScript, on the whole, doesn't try to be invasive at runtime. There were discussions early on about things such as:

- Enforcing types at runtime
- Making private variables actually private at runtime

... and probably more subtle but similar questions.

The result was that TypeScript doesn't want to take over from JavaScript, so it works at design and compile time and outputs idiomatic JavaScript at the end.

This means there are many cases where TypeScript rules can be violated in *other code* such as access modifiers and read only arrays - but that isn't the goal of the project.

Answer (score 1):

That's because interfaces and types, like the access modifiers (private and public) are just Typescript concepts that don't survive the compilation process: ***While coding***, the compiler/IDE will warn you when you are doing something wrong, but once your code becomes pure Javascript, nothing prevents you to assign a string to a number declared variable or to access a private member.

Just an example from the online demo:

[image]

You can see that there are two errors in the Typescript code (left):

- that attribute is private
- that attribute is not a number

But that code would be valid code once transpiled (actually, if you click on Run, it does).

Types and interfaces are useful just to help to detect potential errors, but they don't exist in runtime

Comment: thanks for the answer , the idea is clear for me now